# C# Command Run remote System

Tags: c#, ssh, remote-access

I have to Run a command in Unix System from my C# Application running on Windows.
The two system is in same network and I have all the required credentials.

Is there is any API from which I can run "ls" command of UNIX from C# code by
establishing a SSH connection.

**EDIT:**
I am looking for a solution which will help in running any command or script present 
in Remote System.

Answer (score 19):

Systems that run SSH usually support some kind of SFTP, so you could just use something like [SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/):

```
using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient("localhost", "root", "bugmenot")
{
    sftpClient.Connect();
    var files = sftpClient.ListDirectory("/tmp");
}
```

or [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx):

```
Sftp sftp = new Sftp("localhost", "root", "bugmenot");
try
{
    sftp.Connect();
    ArrayList files = sftp.GetFileList("/tmp");
}
finally
{
    sftp.Close();
}
```

*Edit*: You can run any command over SSH with both libraries. Admittedly, I have not done that, yet, but it is supposed to work like this:

[SSH.NET](http://sshnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5754#96239)

```
using (var sshClient = new SshClient("localhost", "root", "bugmenot")
{
    sshClient.Connect();
    var cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("ls");
    var output = cmd.Result;
}
```

[SharpSSH](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx)

```
SshStream ssh = new SshStream("localhost", "root", "bugmenot");
try
{
    ssh.Write("ls");
    var output = ssh.ReadResponse();
}
finally
{
    ssh.Close();
}
```

Comment: OK, but that is only a substitute for "ls". I gather that might have been a simple example for _any_ command.

Comment: @Hangy: Thanks for replying. I could not able to run your suggested code as I have to get system with all .Net setup. .....I am looking for a solution which will handy to run any command or script which is in Remote System.(Thanks Henk Holterman) .

Comment: Sorry, I have not used that myself, but I hope the example in my edit and the added links help you to achieve that!

Comment: @user430294 do you mean that you can't use third-party components? Then you are out of luck -- .NET doesn't have built-in SSH support. You would have to write an SSH client from scratch or use third-party library. The ones mentioned by hangy above are free and unsupported. We offer our supported components: http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ssh.php .

Comment: @Eugene : I can use third-party components if it is free ware or opensource. :)

Comment: @user430294: Any luck with this approach?

Comment: you forgot a line in ssh.net 2nd example. You must do a sshclient.Connect() after the using :)

Comment: @vrbilgi SSH.NET is both free, and Open Source. I don't see the problem.

Comment: Can you also stop a program? E.g. i need to start executing some program and stop it after some Time. I could imagine to save the PID of the started process on the remote and then stop it.

Comment: I don't see why that shouldn't be possible. After all, these command just run a shell command, so scripting something like that should work.

Comment: Small typo in the example of SSH.NET. You should close the bracket after password string.